# Django: order elements of a form field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models named Quiz and Course

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes',)
```

and

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I'm using quiz model in a createview.

```
class newQuiz(CreateView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'teacher/new_quiz.html'
    fields = ['name', 'course', ]
```

course field is shown as an choice field in the form how can i order the course choices in ascending order while showing in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to provide a default odering for the `Course` model with the [**`ordering`** meta option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

or you can patch the form in the `CreateView` itself by overriding [**`.get_form(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form):

```
class CreateQuizView(CreateView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'teacher/new_quiz.html'
    fields = [
        'name',
        'course',
    ]

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.fields['course'].queryset = Course.objects.order_by('name')
        return form
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much this worked but is it possible to do it inside the view itself, ordering the model will change it everywhere i access that model, for now i want to order by name only in this view @willem

Comment: @ShuvamJaswal: yes, you can patch the form in the `get_form` method.

Comment: hello i just tried your code and it solved my problem, i had an error while copy pasting your code, error was super(): no arguments so i changed the code a little bit               `def get_form(self, form_class=None):`
        `form = super().get_form(form_class)`                                                                            and it worked, can u tell me where can i learn these things like u knew that we can override a field in this way and all. @willem